# I can't paste something between tags in vs code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I think that I pressed something wrong that made me unable to paste something between tags, or in general I can't paste something in the middle of the sentence, whenever I try to paste something it goes before the opening tag (in the start of the sentence). Any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS code, if you place the cursor at the end of the line and `Copy`, then `Paste` it will paste to new line.
You can choose whole line and `Copy` then `Paste` Or refer this link to config `Macros`: [Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791340/vscode-copy-and-paste-1-line-without-newline-character-being-prepended)