# VSCode copy-paste problem - it removes indentation and adds extra blank line below on paste

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode has some copy-paste problem. I copy a line without selecting a line, just click on the line and press `ctrl+c`.

But when I paste (`ctrl+v`) the copied line it removes indentation and adds extra blank line below. How can I fix it?

[image: img]

Comment: Why are you confused?  Please look carefully to GIF. I'm not selecting line, just "ctrl+c" and "ctrl+v"

Answer (score 1):

I found a partial solution to the problem. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72295858/9904870) I Added these lines to `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+v",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": { "snippet": "$CLIPBOARD" },
  "when": "inputFocus"
}
```

But now when I make paste operation it puts extra space:

[image]

So, how to trimLeft copied line, this is the question!

**UPDATE**: Full solution by using extension is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53795818/16644879).